# AMD GPU won't work with Blender's "Cycles Render" on Linux

Tags: linux, blender, fedora, amd-gpu

I've been working a lot with Blender and its "Cycles Render" on Fedora lately. But Blender keeps getting a lot slower while rendering. So I discovered that my Blender is only capable of rendering with my CPU. I tried running Blender from the terminal, so I could see any errors. And if I set "Device" to "GPU Compute" in the rendering settings, I get this output:

```
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [2]
param: 4, val: 0
```

My machine's specifications are:

- Operaring system: Fedora GNU/Linux 27
- Blender version: 2.79
- Graphics card: AMD Radeon RX 480 using `amdgpu` driver (default open-source driver)

So it seems like, Blender's Cycle Render won't work with my AMD GPU...
Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure that message is a failure, do you get any difference after setting gpu render? Have you changed [tile size](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/44428/935)? While [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7486/935) is long and mostly about nvidia, you will find some opencl info at the bottom. Start by checking if you can get opencl working with other things, like [clinfo](https://github.com/Oblomov/clinfo) or [clpeak](https://github.com/krrishnarraj/clpeak).

Comment: @sambler The blender documentation says, that I could start blender with "--debug-value 256", to get some render debug settings. Now I've an extra "debug" tab so change OpenCL settings and I can change the kernel to "mega". Now I could choose my graphics card as a opencl device. But when I tried to render with these settings, blender crashed...

OpenCL error (AMD Radeon (TM) RX 480 Graphics (AMD POLARIS10 / DRM 3.19.0 / 4.14.14-300.fc27.x86_64, LLVM 5.0.0)): Shader Stats: SGPRS: 27 VGPRS: 49 Code Size: 7068 LDS: 10 Scratch: 0 Max Waves: 5 Spilled SGPRs: 0 Spilled VGPRs: 0 PrivMem VGPRs: 0

Comment: Best I can suggest is to [report it as a bug](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/1/),  the RX480 looks to be a supported device.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've seen on the release docs, the Blender cycles engine is not yet fully optimized for all AMD graphics cards, currently they only support AMD cards with GCN architecture 2.0 and above. The dev team focuses on NVIDIA cards mostly (also blender is most optimized for windows).

However, you might as well try to change the settings, first you must make sure you are using OpenCL and not CUDA in your User Preferences, under the System tab, Compute Device(s). Then if your card is not supported, enable the experimental features on the render properties of your workspace, which warn you that will make everything go unstable, this usually enables most AMD GPUs to be selectable as a render device. here on the render properties, you will also be selecting the compute device you desire to use for each scene.

Also, Using an official AMD driver would make rendering faster (also this is a requirement by Blender to use AMD cards) but its not available for fedora as far as I know. I suggest changing your distro to Ubuntu.

**EDIT**: You MUST use an official AMD driver for the desired card, I have checked the card you have **is** on the list of supported cards, just that it **IS** a requirement to have the AMD driver and not opensource. this is the list of supported cards https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units, according to the blender documentation.
But it must be a driver from this list: https://support.amd.com/en-us/download/linux, according to the blender documentation.

Now if that doesn't solve the issue then it must be a hardware issue or blender bug, although you could try to run it on windows to discard it being a hardware issue, if you are willing to do a dual boot or usb boot test.

Comment: https://developer.blender.org/T53935 - I think you already posted it as a bug right? 

well yeah, just switch your distro or dual boot ^-^'

lol I didn't notice being so late to answering... this question is like 12 days old..